# Javafx GUI programming

Tags: user-interface, javafx

So im trying to make 3 buttons on the top panel and 3 radio buttons on the bottom panel, but when i run it, it comes out all weird, would love it if someone can help me. Im still pretty new to GUI so my code might be completely wrong.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;


public class ColorFactory extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        // sets the width and height
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.setWidth(500);

        //calls the mainpanel constructor
        pane.setCenter(new MainPanel());
        //make the mainpanel visible using the setVisible(true)

        //call the stage.setScene
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        // set title to Color Factory
        stage.setTitle("Color Factory");
        //call stage.show
        stage.show();
    }
    private class MainPanel extends BorderPane
    {

        public MainPanel()
        {
            HBox Tpanel = new HBox(25);
            Tpanel = new HBox(25);
            Tpanel.setPrefWidth(500);
            Tpanel.setPrefHeight(50);
            Tpanel.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
            Button red = new Button("Red");
            red.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
            Button yellow = new Button("Yellow");
            yellow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
            Button orange = new Button("Orange");
            orange.setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange;");
            Tpanel.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
            Tpanel.getChildren().addAll(red,yellow,orange);

            HBox Bpanel = new HBox(15);
            Bpanel.setPrefWidth(500);
            Bpanel.setPrefHeight(75);
            RadioButton green = new RadioButton("Green");
            RadioButton  blue = new RadioButton("Blue");
            RadioButton cyan = new RadioButton("Cyan"); 
            green.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
            blue.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
            cyan.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cyan;");
            Bpanel.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
            Bpanel.getChildren().addAll(green,blue,cyan);

            Label label = new Label("Top buttons change the panel color and bottom radio buttons change the text color");
            label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            label.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);

            getChildren().addAll(Tpanel,Bpanel,label);
            HBox.setMargin(Tpanel, new Insets(5,10,5,10));
            HBox.setMargin(Bpanel, new Insets(5,10,5,10));
            HBox.setMargin(label, new Insets(150,10,5,10));

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MainPanel` is a `BorderPane`: simply adding nodes to it will put them all in the top left by default (so they are all on top of each other). When using a `BorderPane`, you need to call `setCenter(...)`, `setTop(...)`, `setLeft(...)` etc to position the nodes.

E.g.:

```
    //  getChildren().addAll(Tpanel,Bpanel,label);
    setTop(Tpanel);
    setBottom(Bpanel);
    setCenter(label);
```

Comment: getChildren().addAll(Tpanel,Bpanel,label);
   setTop(Tpanel);
   setBottom(Bpanel);
   setCenter(label);      like this? I had not errors, but the program didnt run.

Comment: I ran the program: it ran fine. It just had the controls in the wrong place. Just replace the line you have with the lines of code I showed in the answer.